# Uncaught PDOException

Tags: php

Me aparece el siguiente error en un formulario de registro que cree.

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
> number of bound variables does not match number of tokensin
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\modelo\musu.php:51 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\modelo\musu.php(51):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\controlador\cusu.php(37): musu->usuiu(NULL,
> 'prueba', 'uno', '5', '1234567891', 'jhondavisgamer@...',
> 'jhonatan12345', '1') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\vista\vreg.php(2):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\index.php(35):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mybookings\modelo\musu.php on line 51

Este es el codigo cabe recalcar que trabajo mvc

Modelo

```
<?php
class musu{

//Método de Insertar usuario
    public function usuiu($idusu, $nomusu, $apeusu, $pefid, $telusu, $emausu, $pasusu, $actusu){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "CALL usuiu(:idusu, :nomusu, :pefid, :telusu, :emausu, :pasusu, :actusu);";

        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $error = $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
        $result->bindParam(':nomusu',$nomusu);
        $result->bindParam(':apeusu',$apeusu);
        $result->bindParam(':pefid',$pefid);
        $result->bindParam(':telusu',$telusu);
        $result->bindParam(':emausu',$emausu);

        if($pasusu){
            $pas = sha1(md5($pasusu));
            $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas); 
        }else{
            $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pasusu);  
        }
        $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas);
        $result->bindParam(':actusu',$actusu);

        try {
            $result->execute();
            echo "<script>alert('Datos insertados existosamente');</script>";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == '23000')
                echo "<script>alert('Error: El email ya se encuentra registrado')</script>";
                //echo "Syntax Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }









        
        if(!$result)
                echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL INSERTAR/ACTUALIZAR');</script>";
            else
                $result->execute();

    }

//Método de mostrar usuarios
    public function selusu($filtro,$rvalini,$rvalfin){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql ="SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid";

        if($filtro){
            $filtro2 = "%".$filtro."%";
            $sql.=" WHERE u.nomusu LIKE :filtro2 OR u.apeusu LIKE :filtro2 OR p.pefnom LIKE :filtro2 OR u.telusu=:filtro OR u.emausu LIKE :filtro2";
        }
        $sql.= " ORDER BY u.idusu LIMIT $rvalini, $rvalfin;";
        
            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            if($filtro){
                $result->bindParam(':filtro',$filtro);
                $result->bindParam(':filtro2',$filtro2);
            }

            $result->execute();

            while($f=$result->fetch()){
                $resultado[]=$f;
            }

            return $resultado;
    }

//Método contar los registros de usuarios
    public function sqlcount($filtro){
        $sql = "SELECT count(u.idusu) AS Npe FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil as p ON u.pefid=p.pefid ";
        if($filtro)
            $sql .= "  WHERE u.nomusu LIKE '%$filtro% OR u.apeusu LIKE '%$filtro% OR p.pefnom LIKE '%$filtro% OR u.telusu='%$filtro% OR u.emausu LIKE '%$filtro%";
        return $sql;
    }

    public function seluser(){
            $resultado = null;
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid";

            $sql .= " ORDER BY u.idusu";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>".$filtro."<br>";

            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

            $result->execute();

            while($f=$result->fetch()){
                $resultado[]=$f;
            }

            return $resultado;
        }

//Método de mostrar un usuario
    public function selusu1($idusu){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql ="SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid WHERE u.idusu=:idusu";

        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
        $result->execute();
        while($f=$result->fetch()){
            $resultado[]=$f;
        }
        return $resultado;
    }

//Método de eliminar usuarios
    public function usudel($idusu){
            $resultado = null;
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "CALL usudel(:idusu)";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>".$filtro."<br>";

            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
            
            if(!$result)
                echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL ELIMINAR');</script>";
            else
                $result->execute();
        }

//Metodo muestre los Perfiles
    public function selpef(){
        $resultado=null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT pefid, pefnom FROM perfil ORDER BY pefnom";
        //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>";
        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $result->execute();

        while($f=$result->fetch()){
            $resultado[]=$f;
        }
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function actusu($idusu,$actusu){
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET actusu=:actusu WHERE idusu=:idusu;";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>'".$idusu."'";
            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
            $result->bindParam(':actusu',$actusu);

            if(!$result)
                echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL REGISTRAR')</script>";
            else
                $result->execute();
        }
}
?>
```

Aqui el controlador

```
<?php
require_once 'modelo/conexion.php';
require_once 'modelo/musu.php';
require_once 'modelo/mpagina.php';

$pg=305;
$arc="home.php";
$musu = new musu();

$idusu = isset($_POST["idusu"]) ? $_POST["idusu"]:NULL;
if(!$idusu){
    $idusu = isset($_GET["idusu"]) ? $_GET["idusu"]:NULL;
}

$nomusu = isset($_POST['nomusu']) ? $_POST['nomusu']:NULL;
$apeusu = isset($_POST['apeusu']) ? $_POST['apeusu']:NULL;
$pefid = isset($_POST['pefid']) ? $_POST['pefid']:5;
$telusu = isset($_POST['telusu']) ? $_POST['telusu']:NULL;
$emausu = isset($_POST['emausu']) ? $_POST['emausu']:NULL;
$pasusu = isset($_POST['pasusu']) ? $_POST['pasusu']:NULL;
$actusu = isset($_GET['actusu']) ? $_GET['actusu']:1;

$filtro = isset($_POST['filtro']) ? $_POST['filtro']:NULL;
if(!$filtro){
    $filtro = isset($_GET['filtro']) ? $_GET['filtro']:NULL;
}

$opera = isset($_POST['opera']) ? $_POST['opera']:NULL;
if(!$opera){
    $opera = isset($_GET['opera']) ? $_GET['opera']:NULL;
}
echo "<br>".$idusu."-".$nomusu."-".$apeusu."-".$pefid."-".$telusu."-".$emausu."-".$pasusu."-".$filtro."<br><br>";

//Insertar
if($opera=="InsAct"){
        if($nomusu && $apeusu && $pefid && $emausu){
            $musu->usuiu($idusu, $nomusu, $apeusu, $pefid, $telusu, $emausu, $pasusu, $actusu);
                echo "<script>alert('Datos insertados y/o actualizados exitosamente');</script>";
            $idusu = NULL;
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Faltan llenar algunos campos');</script>";
        }
    }
//Eliminar
    if($opera=="Elim"){
        if($idusu){
            $musu->usudel($idusu);
                echo "<script>alert('Datos eliminados exitosamente');</script>";
        }
    }
if($opera=="ActuOK"){
    if($idusu && $actusu)
        $musu->actusu($idusu,$actusu);
    $idusu = "";
}

if($idusu){
    $GLOBALS['nu'] = 1;
    $GLOBALS['alto'] = "750px";
}


//Paginacion parte 1
$bo = "";
$nreg = 17;
$pa = new mpagina();
$preg = $pa->mpagin($nreg);
$conp = $musu->sqlcount($filtro);

function insdatos($idusu,$pg,$arc){
        $musu = new musu(); 
        $dtpef = $musu->selpef();
        $dtusu = NULL;
        $perfil = isset($_SESSION["pefid"]) ? $_SESSION["pefid"]:NULL;

        if($idusu) $dtusu = $musu->selusu1($idusu);

        $txt = '';
        $txt .= '<div class="conte">';
            if ($pg==201) {
                $txt .= '<h2>Registro de Usuario</h2>';
            }elseif($pg=="314"){
                $txt .= '<h2>Actualizar mis datos</h2>';
            }else{
                $txt .= tit("Nuevo usuario","far fa-plus-square ico3",$arc,$pg,"700px",2);
                $txt .= '<div id="inser">'; 
                
            }
            
            $txt .= '<form name="frm1" action="'.$arc.'?pg='.$pg.'" method="POST">';

            if($idusu && $dtusu){
                $txt .= '<label>Id del Usuario</label>';
                $txt .= '<input type="number" name="idusu" readonly value="'.$idusu.'" class="form-control" />';
            }

            $txt .= '<label>Nombre del Usuario</label>';
            $txt .= '<input type="text" name="nomusu" maxlength="50" class="form-control" onkeypress="return sololet(event);"';
                if($idusu && $dtusu) $txt .= ' value="'.$dtusu[0]['nomusu'].'"';
                $txt .= ' required />';

            $txt .= '<label>Apellido del Usuario</label>';
            $txt .= '<input type="text" name="apeusu" maxlength="50" class="form-control" onkeypress="return sololet(event);"';
                if($idusu && $dtusu) $txt .= ' value="'.$dtusu[0]['apeusu'].'"';
                $txt .= ' required />';

//Perfil
            if($perfil==1){
                $txt .= '<label>Perfil del Usuario</label>';
                $txt .= '<select name="pefid" class="form-control" required>';
                    if($dtpef){
                        foreach ($dtpef as $f) {
                            $txt .= '<option value="'.$f['pefid'].'"';
                            if ($idusu && $dtusu && $f['pefid']==$dtusu[0]['pefid']) $txt .= " selected ";
                            $txt .= '>'.$f['pefnom'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                $txt .= '</select>';
            }

            $txt .= '<label>Telefono:</label>';
            $txt .= '<input type="number" name="telusu" maxlength="10" class="form-control"onkeypress="return solonum(event);" ';
                if($idusu && $dtusu) $txt .= ' value="'.$dtusu[0]['telusu'].'"';
                $txt .= '/>';
            
            $txt .= '<label>E-mail: </label>';
            $txt .= '<input type="email" name="emausu" maxlength="100" class="form-control"';
                if($idusu && $dtusu) $txt .= ' value="'.$dtusu[0]['emausu'].'"';
                $txt .= ' required />';

            $txt .= '<label>Crea una contraseña: </label>';
            $txt .= '<input type="password" name="pasusu" class="form-control"';
            if ($arc=="home.php") 
                $txt .= '>';
            else
                $txt .=' required>';    

            $txt .= '<input type="hidden" name="opera" value="InsAct">';
                $txt .= '<div class="cen">';
                    $txt .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="';
                    if($idusu && $dtusu)
                        $txt .= 'Actualizar';
                    else
                        $txt .= 'Registrar';
                    $txt .= '">';
                $txt .= '</div>';
            $txt .= '</form>';
        $txt .= '</div>';
        $txt .= '<br><br><br>';
        echo $txt;
    }
?>
```

Aqui esta la vista

```
<?php
    include("controlador/cusu.php");
    insdatos($idusu,"201","index.php");
?>  
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: El error dice que se le está enviando una cantidad distinta de parámetros de la que requiere. Quizás sea porque se bindea dos veces `$pasusu`. O porque `idusu` es null.

Comment: Como recomendación modifica el titulo de tu pregunta que sea mas descriptivo y nunca insinúes "urgencia" normalmente este tipo de preguntas terminan cerradas te invito a leer [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Resumiendo tu consulta espera 7 parámetros pero solo haces binding de 6

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas una recompensa para la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

La Excepción *`Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`* ocurre cuando el número de parámetros que indicas en la consulta preparada no coincide con el número de parámetros que pasas en el método *bind*.

**Parte** del problema está aquí:

```
    if($pasusu){
        $pas = sha1(md5($pasusu));
        $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas); #1er bind aquí
    }else{
        $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pasusu); #o 1er bind aquí
    }
    $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas); #y 2º bind aquí ... no está bien esto
    $result->bindParam(':actusu',$actusu);
```

Tú estarías haciendo *bind* de `:pasusu` **dos veces**, en el `if ... else` y también fuera de él.

Para evitar esta confusión, es mucho más simple usar un condicional para determinar qué valor tendrá la variable y luego hacer *bind* de ese valor. En el código más abajo usaré un ternario para asignar el valor que deba tener la variable (`$pas`) y luego hacemos *bind* de ella cualquiera que sea su valor. Dicho de otro modo: **aplica la lógica para crear la variable, no para hacer los *bind***.

**Pero**, hay algunas incongruencias y malas prácticas adicionales en tu código. Tratemos de ver las más graves:

Este trozo de código no tiene mucho sentido (ya arriba señalé el doble *bind* que esto provoca, pero ahora es preciso que te des cuenta de un error de lógica aparte de eso).

Si analizamos esto:

```
    if($pasusu){
        $pas = sha1(md5($pasusu));
        $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas); 
    }else{
        $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pasusu);  
    }
```

Lo que estás diciendo es que si `$pasusu` es `true`  (existe o lo que sea) que haga lo que indicas en el primer bloque... OK ... pero de lo contrario que haga un *bind* de un valor `false` o `null`  ¿? Creo que debes aclararte en ese punto. ¿Se admiten passwords con valor `null` o `false` en tu modelo de datos? Si se admiten es absurdo desde el punto de vista de la seguridad y si no se admiten tu código está mal escrito... O sea, malll por donde quiera que lo mires.

Seguimos con más errores...

Estás intentando hacer *bind*  de un parámetro `:apeusu` que no existe en la consulta preparada... debes aclararte también en ese punto. ¿Tu SP debe recibir un parámetro con respecto al apellido? Si es así debes ponerlo en el `CALL` ¿no? En la respuesta he comentado esa línea del código, asumiendo que ha sido un error tuyo. Pero si el SP debe recibir ese parámetro tu código PHP debe ser congruente en ese sentido o no funcionará aunque esté escrito correctamente desde el punto de vista sintáctico.

Más cosas...

Considera meter todos los procesos que pueden fallar dentro del `try`, así podrás capturar los errores. Considera además poner todo lo que sea relativo a la configuración de la conexión antes de usarla.

Más aún ...

Tu manejo del `execute()` también es confuso. Por ejemplo, ejecutas dos veces. Sí sí, **cada vez que llamas a `execute()` lo que ocurre es que la consulta preparada se ejecuta**. Significa que podrías estar haciendo una doble llamada a la SP. Si quieres evaluar el resultado de `execute()` puedes ponerlo en un `if` (como he hecho en el código más abajo), o guardar una referencia en una variable y luego usar esa variable.

Además, lo haces fuera del `try`. Todo eso aporta confusión al código. Como dije antes, pon dentro del `try` todas las operaciones relativas a la consulta... Podrás capturar cualquier error en el `catch`. Ese es el sentido de los bloques `try ... catch`.

Hay más cosas (viendo someramente las otras funcioens de tu clase), pero sería muy extenso para una sola pregunta y aquí nos centramos en el error que planteas en la pregunta.

Ahora te sugiero un código organizado que hará *bind* una sola vez de cada parámetro. Dado que son muchos cambios, he puesto comentarios en los puntos neurálgicos. Si aún tienes dudas pregunta en comentarios en esta respuesta.

```
<?php
class musu{

//Método de Insertar usuario
    public function usuiu($idusu, $nomusu, $apeusu, $pefid, $telusu, $emausu, $pasusu, $actusu){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $error = $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        /*
          Esto hace lo mismo que tu if, 
          pero aquí usamos un ternario. 
          A esto me refería cuando decía que no
          traslades la lógica a los bind...
          Lo propio es definir la variable. 
          Simplemente asignamos a $pas el valor de la izquierda 
          o su valor original que será false o null  ¿? 
          Como comenté en la respuesta, debes aclararte en este punto 
        */

        $pas=($pasusu) ? sha1(md5($pasusu)) : $pasusu;

        try {
                /*
                  Trasladamos todo este bloque dentro del try ... 
                  En el CALL no existe el parámetro :apeusu ¿?
                */
                $sql = "CALL usuiu(:idusu, :nomusu, :pefid, :telusu, :emausu, :pasusu, :actusu);";
                $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
          
                $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
                $result->bindParam(':nomusu',$nomusu);
                $result->bindParam(':pefid',$pefid);
                /*
                  Este parámetro no está en la consulta preparada 
                  por tanto lo dejo comentado en el código ...
                */
                //$result->bindParam(':apeusu',$apeusu);
                $result->bindParam(':telusu',$telusu);
                $result->bindParam(':emausu',$emausu);

                /*
                  Ya definimos arriba el valor condicional de $pas 
                  Aquí simplemente hacemos el bind 
                  Así todo queda más organizado 
                */
                $result->bindParam(':pasusu',$pas); 
                $result->bindParam(':actusu',$actusu);

                /*
                   Tu evaluación del execute era errónea y fuera de sitio 
                   Por ejemplo, estabas haciendo el execute dos veces ...
                   Basta con verificar con un if y en el else mostrar el error 
                   OJO: al usar try ... catch ... puede que algunos errores 
                   sean capturados en el catch por lo que debes dar claridad a tu código
                   también en ese aspecto
                */
                if ($result->execute()) {
                  echo "<script>alert('Datos insertados existosamente');</script>";
                } else {
                  echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL INSERTAR/ACTUALIZAR');</script>";
                }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == '23000') {
                echo "<script>alert('Error: El email ya se encuentra registrado')</script>";
            }
            /*
              ¿Qué ocurre con los errores que no son 23000? 
            */
                //echo "Syntax Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }

    }

//Método de mostrar usuarios
    public function selusu($filtro,$rvalini,$rvalfin){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql ="SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid";

        if($filtro){
            $filtro2 = "%".$filtro."%";
            $sql.=" WHERE u.nomusu LIKE :filtro2 OR u.apeusu LIKE :filtro2 OR p.pefnom LIKE :filtro2 OR u.telusu=:filtro OR u.emausu LIKE :filtro2";
        }
        $sql.= " ORDER BY u.idusu LIMIT $rvalini, $rvalfin;";
        
            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            if($filtro){
                $result->bindParam(':filtro',$filtro);
                $result->bindParam(':filtro2',$filtro2);
            }

            $result->execute();

            while($f=$result->fetch()){
                $resultado[]=$f;
            }

            return $resultado;
    }

//Método contar los registros de usuarios
    public function sqlcount($filtro){
        $sql = "SELECT count(u.idusu) AS Npe FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil as p ON u.pefid=p.pefid ";
        if($filtro)
            $sql .= "  WHERE u.nomusu LIKE '%$filtro% OR u.apeusu LIKE '%$filtro% OR p.pefnom LIKE '%$filtro% OR u.telusu='%$filtro% OR u.emausu LIKE '%$filtro%";
        return $sql;
    }

    public function seluser(){
            $resultado = null;
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid";

            $sql .= " ORDER BY u.idusu";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>".$filtro."<br>";

            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

            $result->execute();

            while($f=$result->fetch()){
                $resultado[]=$f;
            }

            return $resultado;
        }

//Método de mostrar un usuario
    public function selusu1($idusu){
        $resultado = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql ="SELECT u.idusu, u.nomusu, u.apeusu, u.pefid, p.pefnom, u.telusu, u.emausu, u.actusu FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN perfil AS p ON u.pefid=p.pefid WHERE u.idusu=:idusu";

        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
        $result->execute();
        while($f=$result->fetch()){
            $resultado[]=$f;
        }
        return $resultado;
    }

//Método de eliminar usuarios
    public function usudel($idusu){
            $resultado = null;
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "CALL usudel(:idusu)";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>".$filtro."<br>";

            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
            
            if(!$result)
                echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL ELIMINAR');</script>";
            else
                $result->execute();
        }

//Metodo muestre los Perfiles
    public function selpef(){
        $resultado=null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT pefid, pefnom FROM perfil ORDER BY pefnom";
        //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>";
        $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $result->execute();

        while($f=$result->fetch()){
            $resultado[]=$f;
        }
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function actusu($idusu,$actusu){
            $modelo = new conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET actusu=:actusu WHERE idusu=:idusu;";
            //echo "<br><br><br><br>".$sql."<br>'".$idusu."'";
            $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            //echo $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $result->bindParam(':idusu',$idusu);
            $result->bindParam(':actusu',$actusu);

            if(!$result)
                echo "<script>alert('ERROR AL REGISTRAR')</script>";
            else
                $result->execute();
        }
}
?>
```